# Error: formGroup expects a FormGroup instance. Please pass one in. Using example code and still getting error

Tags: angular, forms

I know this has been asked a thousand times, but 99% of the solutions seem to be typos. I have reduced the code to what is actually suggested in the error message:

[image: error]

In my html:

```
<div [formGroup]="myGroup">
  <input formControlName="firstName">
</div>
```

In my ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-my-info',
  templateUrl: './my-info.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./my-info.component.scss']
})
export class MyInfoComponent implements OnInit {

  myGroup: FormGroup;


  ngOnInit() {
    this.myGroup = new FormGroup({
      firstName: new FormControl()
    });
  }

}
```

I have spent hours and hours on this. The code is working elsewhere in my app. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What formsModule have u imported to the featuremodule?

Comment: I hope you have imported `FormsModule` in your module which has your component [i.e. app.module.ts]?

Comment: can you reproduce your issue https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackoverflow-57362093?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: @Jacksnap13, please chack my comment to the response of Obl. Really I think that the place to create the form is in the ngOnInit

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that the problem is you are doing this inside `ngOnInit()`. Read up on lifecycle hooks: https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks

In the [official docs](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms) it shows the form being setup just as a variable

```
export class ProfileEditorComponent {
  profileForm = new FormGroup({
    firstName: new FormControl(''),
    lastName: new FormControl(''),
  });
}
```

Comment: another option I like more is use in .html `<form *ngIf="myGroup" [formGroup]="myGroup">`

Answer (score 0):

Wow. Thanks for all of your input everyone. It turned out I had another component of the same name buried elsewhere in the application. My ts file was not even being recognized.  Angular works in mysterious ways :(

Answer (score 0):

At form tag in your component.html add this: ***ngIf="{your form group name}"**

for example:

```
 <form *ngIf="updateBookForm" [formGroup]="updateBookForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
```